# Why does airflow try to run tasks with sudo on ubuntu server and then fail?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, unix, airflow

I have recently deployed Airflow on an Ubuntu Server by using the official airflow docker image and the docker-compose file as my basis.

In the beginning, everything was running fine on both my local windows 10 machine and on the server.
But since a couple of days all my dags/tasks fail on the server with the following error message in the logs:

```
    [2021-05-05 09:24:51,274] {taskinstance.py:1063} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): extract_events> on 2021-05-05T08:00:00+00:00
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,274] {base_task_runner.py:133} INFO - Running on host: 206851aec3f2
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,274] {base_task_runner.py:134} INFO - Running: ['sudo', '-E', '-H', '-u', 'airflow', 'airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'events_pipeline', 'extract_events', '2021-05-05T08:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '3', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/sro/events_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpvzvt2zyj', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp8dbgrtf6']
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events 
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events 
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events     #2) Think before you type.
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,287] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events 
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,288] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Job 3: Subtask extract_events sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
[2021-05-05 09:24:51,288] {local_task_job.py:146} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

What I do not understand is, why sudo is used to run the task in  the container, whereas this is not the case when I run it locally for development. I am using the exact same dockerfile and docker compose files locally and on the server.
The docker file looks as follows:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.1
USER root
# Download microsoft drivers for odbc connection
ARG ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential unixodbc-dev msodbcsql17
USER airflow
# Download the apache-airflow plugin for odbc connections
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user apache-airflow[odbc]
USER root
RUN apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
```

And the docker compose file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME         - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                              Default: apache/airflow:master-python3.8
# AIRFLOW_UID                - User ID in Airflow containers
#                              Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_GID                - Group ID in Airflow containers
#                              Default: 50000
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME - Username for the administrator account.
#                              Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD - Password for the administrator account.
#                              Default: airflow
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # This is the image created by running the docker file.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow-odbc:2.0.1}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
  volumes:
    - ./config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that the problem was caused by the entry:
default_impersonation = airflow
in my airflow config file. After removing it, the problem dissapeared.