# linux Run Multiple Commands in Linux, one after another not working

Tags: linux, command, chain

I am just trying to chain commands, but it is not working when trying the solutions recommended.

I am trying to run :

`sudo su - airflow`
THEN
`cd /opt/test_folder`

I tried both of these:

`sudo su - airflow ; cd /opt/test_folder`

`sudo su - airflow && cd /opt/test_folder`

But only the first part runs (`sudo su - airflow`) but not the second (`cd /opt/test_folder`)

Comment: I think su needs -c to pass the commands. `sudo su - -c airflow; cd /opt/test_folder`

Comment: If i do that it prompts me for a password, when it usually doesent

Comment: What is your goal? What commands do you want to run with `airflow` user? It makes no sense to run single `cd` command as it changes working directory for current process only. If you want to run multiple commands run them in one shell, e.g. `sudo su - airflow -c 'cd /opt/test_folder && ...'`

Comment: You can try `-n` after `sudo` for non-interactive, it won't prompt anyway, not sure how that will go with su.  I found this also, it's not directly related, but airflow and sudo have history. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398820/why-does-airflow-try-to-run-tasks-with-sudo-on-ubuntu-server-and-then-fail